# Unity webGL doesn't show videos when uploaded

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-player, unity-webgl

I'm quite new on Unity and is trying to create an interactive film (like Bandersnatch), my builds when ran locally is fully functional but when uploaded (on Itch.io), videos show up as blank but the game objects such as buttons function well.

I've been looking for solutions online for quite some time now and I can't seem to find the solution that I need.

Here is a sample of my code that I use:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;

public class Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    string url;
    VideoPlayer current_clip;
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject this_canvas;


    public GameObject nextdefault;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        switch (gameObject.name)
        {
            case "Intro":
                url = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + "Intro.mp4";
                Invoke("showButtons", 37.0f);
                Invoke("playdefault", 47.0f);
                break;
            case "a_pancakes":
                url = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + "a_pancakes.mp4";
                Invoke("showButtons", 18.0f);
                Invoke("playdefault", 28.0f);
                break;
            case "a_eggs":
                url = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + "a_eggs.mp4";
                Invoke("showButtons", 16.0f);
                Invoke("playdefault", 26.0f);
                break;
           //AND SO ON...
        }
        VideoPlayer thisVideo = GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();

        thisVideo.url = url;
        thisVideo.Play();
        current_clip = GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        //Debug.Log(thisVideo.name);
    }     
    private void playdefault()
    {
        if(gameObject.activeInHierarchy){
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
            nextdefault.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    private void showButtons()
    {
        this_canvas.SetActive(true);
    }

    // public play_
}
```

I hope someone could be of help in identifying my problem.
Thank you in advance

Edit: It seems the uploaded WebGL works on Google Chrome but not on firefox which is still a problem for accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

- Because of you are trying to access 'Application.streamingAssetsPath' directory which is not allow access on android and webgl.
- Check this out.
- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html

Comment: This shed light on my problem and it does seem that I need to use UnityWebRequest to replace Application.streamingAssetsPath, is that right?

Comment: yeah I recommend you that play video with using 'UnityWebRequest'. It works on webgl because I did if before.

Comment: above codes seems only problem with streamingAssetsPath. so make think positive. It would works